# AltoRouter - mapping/routing home class as default

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, altorouter

I get the part how you call your controllers [here](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/issues/57) but how to set 'Home' as default controller and 'index' as default action in [AltoRouter](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter)

this is wrong but something like

```
$router->map('GET', '/', function($controller, $action) {
    $controller = 'Home';
    $action = 'index';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends a little on what you mean by 'default action'.

If you mean "how do I make the `'/'` route go to the `index()` method on my `HomeController` class", then a simplified version of the linked github issue (and [the AltoRouter website](http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html)) would apply:

```
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/example.com'); 
$router->map('GET','/', 'HomeController#index');
$match = $router->match();

if ($match === false) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].' 404 Not Found');
} else {
    list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);
    if ( is_callable([$controller, $action]) ) {
        $obj = new $controller();
        call_user_func_array([$obj, $action], [$match['params']]);
    } else {
        // here your routes are wrong.
        // Throw an exception in debug, send a 500 error in production
    }
}
```

The `#` here is completely arbitrary, it's just a delimiter to separate the controller name from the method being called. [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) uses an `@` for a similar kind of router-to-controller notation (i.e. `HomeController@index`).

If you meant "if in doubt, show the home page as a default action", then it would look fairly similar to the above, the only difference would be that the 404 path would be simply:

```
if ($match === false) {
    $obj = new HomeController();
    $obj->index();
} else {
    // etc.
}
```